APache beam Batch jobs throwing error in GBQ STORAGE_WRITE_API
I am trying to use STORAGE_WRITE_API in Bigquery insert inorder to reduce cost.
code snippet is
inputData.apply(BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().to("table-name)
                        .withClustering()
                        .withTimePartitioning(new TimePartitioning().setType("DAY").setField(TableConstants.LAST_MODIFIED))
                        .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                        .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                        .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STORAGE_WRITE_API)
                );

While running this job in cloud getting the below error
Error message from worker: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Append to stream projects/my-project/datasets/test-dataset/tables/test-table/streams/Cig2OGE4MzRhZC0wMDAwLTI4ZjctYjBkYi1hYzNlYjE0ODkwNTg6czEx failed with stream doesn't exist
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:187)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:108)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.processElement(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.java:128)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.processElement(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowViaIteratorsFn.java:56)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:121)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:117)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:54)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:218)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:169)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:83)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.executeWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:319)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.doWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:291)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.BatchDataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(BatchDataflowWorker.java:221)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:147)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:127)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:114)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UnboundedScheduledExecutorService$ScheduledFutureTask.run(UnboundedScheduledExecutorService.java:163)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Append to stream projects/my-project/datasets/test-dataset/tables/test-table/streams/Cig2OGE4MzRhZC0wMDAwLTI4ZjctYjBkYi1hYzNlYjE0ODkwNTg6czEx failed with stream doesn't exist
    org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords$WriteRecordsDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:188)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:340)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:54)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:285)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$900(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:85)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:423)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:76)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StorageApiConvertMessages$ConvertMessagesDoFn.processElement(StorageApiConvertMessages.java:161)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StorageApiConvertMessages$ConvertMessagesDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:188)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:340)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:54)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.AssignWindowsParDoFnFactory$AssignWindowsParDoFn.processElement(AssignWindowsParDoFnFactory.java:115)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:54)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:285)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$900(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:85)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:423)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:411)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.PrepareWrite$1.processElement(PrepareWrite.java:84)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.PrepareWrite$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:185)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:340)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:54)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:285)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$900(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:85)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:423)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:411)
    test.transformations.fn.TableRowFn.insertTableRow(TableRowFn.java:78)
    test.transformations.fn.TableRowFn.processElement(TableRowFn.java:42)
    test.transformations.fn.TableRowFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:188)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:340)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:54)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:285)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$900(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:85)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:423)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:76)
    test.transformations.fn.UpcSplitTransformFn.processElement(UpcSplitTransformFn.java:261)
    test.transformations.fn.UpcSplitTransformFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:185)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:340)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:54)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:285)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$900(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:85)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:423)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:76)
    test.transformations.fn.UpcMapperTransformFn.processElement(UpcMapperTransformFn.java:266)
    test.transformations.fn.UpcMapperTransformFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:185)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:340)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:44)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:54)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:185)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Append to stream projects/my-project/datasets/test-dataset/tables/test-table/streams/Cig2OGE4MzRhZC0wMDAwLTI4ZjctYjBkYi1hYzNlYjE0ODkwNTg6czEx failed with stream doesn't exist
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords$WriteRecordsDoFn$DestinationState.lambda$flush$8(StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords.java:731)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.RetryManager.await(RetryManager.java:263)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords$WriteRecordsDoFn.flushAll(StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords.java:896)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords$WriteRecordsDoFn.flushIfNecessary(StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords.java:870)
    org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords$WriteRecordsDoFn.process(StorageApiWriteUnshardedRecords.java:993)


This is batch job. Also, If I use STORAGE_API_AT_LEAST_ONCE my batch job is working fine.
Should I use withAutoSharding as well?
can anyone give any inputs on this?
TIA

Have you tried the latest Beam 2.55.1?
